# PDFBox failing with DamagedFontException (Arial font)

Tags: java, exception, fonts, pdfbox

I am trying to parse the existing PDF and it is failing with DamagedFontException.
I looked at the PDF and it is using Arial font. So I am trying right now to add Arial font and this is the error I am getting now.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fontbox/ttf/TTFParser
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.load(PDType0Font.java:147)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.interactive.form.FillFormField.main(FillFormField.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 2 more
```

I modified the existing FillFormField class in PDFBox examples and added the Arial text field to the test PDF and was able to reproduce the error.

Here is the code which I added:

```
PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
acroForm.getDefaultResources().put(
    COSName.getPDFName("Arial"),
    PDType0Font.load(pdfDocument, new File("src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/Arial.ttf")));
```

What I am doing wrong? My main goal is to just fill the form in the document, and that's it.

UPDATE:

The `DamageFontException` happens when I just modify existing PDF in the example

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/fontbox/type1/DamagedFontException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:76)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:143)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.validateAndEnsureAcroFormResources(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:150)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.AppearanceGeneratorHelper.<init>(AppearanceGeneratorHelper.java:111)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.constructAppearances(PDTextField.java:261)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTerminalField.applyChange(PDTerminalField.java:210)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDTextField.setValue(PDTextField.java:218)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.interactive.form.FillFormField.main(FillFormField.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.fontbox.type1.DamagedFontException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates an issue in your class path. Which pdfbox jar and which fontbox jar do you have included? That being said i don't see a `DamagedFontException` (which you claim in your question title) in the stack trace.

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? Hopefully 2.0.22 because that is the current one today.

Comment: I checked out the latest PDFBox from trunk and did mvn clean install,
then I opened FillFormField.pdf used in the FillFormField example and added the text label with the Arial font.  That's how I got DamagedFontException.

Comment: You still need to have pdfbox and fontbox. Alternatively use pdfbox-app which has both. And I'd recommend that stay with the released 2.0.* versions. There's no need to make your own life difficult.

Comment: Furthermore, you say you have added code. But have you also added the Arial font file at the path you claim it is, i.e. at `src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/Arial.ttf`?

Comment: The edit doesn't change that "NoClassDefFoundError" means the class from fontbox is missing.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr here is the demo I created from exiting example in PDFBox, it is all untouched and I am still getting damaged font exception. 

https://github.com/Romsan01/pdf-test

BTW I am on OSX if that matters...

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe something is broken with your local maven repository? If so, rename or delete it so that it gets rebuilt. (it is in the  ~/.m2 directory)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you!! Something wrong was with my .m2 repository. Everything is working fine

Comment: Glad to hear that. Consider answering yourself, mention what you did. (probably the "atomic" solution )